# Baire sets and Borel sets

Tags: baire-category, borel-sets

I need to show that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a Baire set if and only if it is a Borel set.

The Baire set is $\sigma(\kappa)$ where $\kappa$ is the set of all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Let $K$ be a compact set. Then it is closed and hence it is Borel.

Conversely, let U be an open set.

Consider $K_{m}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}:\|x\|\leq m,d(x,U^{c})\ge\frac{1}{m}\}$

Then $K_{m}$ is compact and $U=\cup K_{m}$ and hence $U\in \sigma(\kappa)$.

My question is what is this set $K_{m}$ as I have no idea how it looks like? Why is the open set $U=\cup K_{m}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $K_m$ is bounded (first condition) and closed (by the two conditions). It is a subset of $U$ (second condition). Now show: If $x\in U$ then because $U$ is open, $x$ must belong to some $K_m$ for $m$ large enough and you are done.

Comment: If I consider just one dimension, is it something like $[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$ which is a subset of $(a,b)$ and getting bigger and bigger as $n$ increases?

Comment: Yes, indeed. And the condition  $|x|\leq m$ ensures that the subset remains bounded (if parts of $U$ stretches to infinity).